# Need help with the following puzzle in algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

The function $f : Z → Z$ satisfies $f(n) = n − 3$ if n ≥ 1000 and
$f(n) = f(f(n + 5))$ if $n < 1000$. Find $f(9)$.

Attempt: Clearly, doing this by hand is not the right approach. I am thinking of a generating function

$$G(X) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_nx^n$$

And then you can play around with the bounds and get some formulas. How would you approach this?. Which mathematical principle would you use?

I created a little program for this and got f(9) = 998, so by "engineering induction (lol)", the answer is

c++ code

```
include <iostream>

int math_function(int integer){
    if(integer >= 1000) return integer-3;
    else return math_function(math_function(integer + 5));
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << math_function(9) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a bit and see if you get any insight.

$f(9) = f(f(14)) = f^2(14) = f(f(f(19)))= f^3(19)... etc$.

.....

Prop: $f(9) = f^{n+1}(9 + 5n)$ so long as $9 + 5n < 1000$.  Pf: follows by induction $f(9) = f^{k+1}(9+5k)  = f^k(f(9 + 5k))=f^k(f(f(9 + 5k + 5)))= f^{k+2}(9 + 5(k+1))$

.....

So $f(9)= f^{199}(999)$

Noodling: for a large enough $M$:

$f^{M}(999) = f^{M-1}(f(999)) = f^{M-1}(f(f(1004))) = f^{M-1}(f(1001)) = f^{M-1}(998)$

$=f^{M-2}(f(998)) = f^{M-2}(f(f(1003))) = f^{M-2}(f(1000)) = f^{M-2}(997)$

$=f^{M-3}(f(997)) = f^{M-3}(f(f(1002)) = f^{M-3}(f(999)) = f^{M-2}(999)$.

.....

So $f(9) = f^{199}(999) = f(999) = f(f(1004)) = f(1001) = 998$.

....

post-script:

In hindsight.

$f(999) = f(f(1004)) = f(1001) = 998$.

$f(998) = f(f(1003)) = f(1000) = 997$

$f(997) = f(f(1002)) = f(999) = 998$.

$f(996) = f(f(1001)) = f(998) = 997$.

$f(995) = f(f(1000)) = f(997) = 998$.

So for $995 \le n < 1000$ $f(n) = 998$ if $n$ is odd and $f(n) = 997$ if $n$ is even.

And as $f(998) = 997$ and $f(997) = 998$. for $995\le n < 1000, f(n) = f^{2j + 1}(n)$.

If $n = r + 5k < 1000; 0\le r < 5$ then

$f(n) = f^{m+1}(r + 5(k+m))$

Let $m = 199 - k$.

$f(n) = f^{200-k}(r + 995)$

So if $k$ is odd and $995 + r$ is odd $f(n) = 998$.

If $k$ is even and $995 +r$ is odd $f(n) = 997$.

If $k$ is odd and $995 +r$ is even $f(n) = 997$.

If $k$ is even and $995 + r$ is even $f(n) = 998$.

So if $k+r$ is odd $f(n) = 998$ and if $k+r$ is even $f(n) = 997$

If $n = r + 5k \equiv r \mod 10$ if $k$ is even and $n\equiv r + 5$ if $k$ is odd.  If $n \equiv s \mod 10$ then $k+r$ is even/odd if and only if $s$ is if and only if $n$ is.

So $f(n) =  $

$998$ if $n< 1000$ and $n$ is odd.

$997$ if $n < 1000$ and $n$ is even.

$n -3$ if $n \ge 100$.

===== Induction proof ====

Prop: For $n < 1000$, $f(n) = 997$ if $n$ is odd and $f(n) =998$ if $n$ is even.

Inductive step:

If true of all $k > n$ and $n < 995$. then $f(n) =f(f(n+5) ) = f(998 \text{ if n is even}, 997 \text{is n is odd}) = 997 $ if $n$ is even or $998$ if $n$ is odd.

Base cases:

If true for $n = 999, 998$ and $n = 995, 996,997$ then

$f(n) = f(f(n+5)) = f(n+2)$ so holds for $n =995, 996,997$.

$f(998) = f(f(1003)) = f(1000) = 997; f(999) = f(f(1004)) = f(1001)=998$.

Answer (score 3):

Just reverse engineer your engineering induction; i.e. Turn it into Mathematical induction !
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(9)=f(f(14))=f(f(f(19)))= \cdots = \underbrace{f(f( \cdots f(}_{199 \text{ times}}999) \cdots )).
\end{eqnarray*}
Now evaluate these
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(999)&=&f(f(1004))=f(1001)= 998 \\
f(f(999))&=&f(998)=f(f(1003)=f(1000)=997 \\
f(f(f(999)))&=&f(997)=f(f(1002))=f(999)=998 \\
\vdots \\
\underbrace{f(f( \cdots f(}_{199 \text{ times}}999) \cdots ))&=&\color{blue}{ 998}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

$$
f(n) = f(f(n+5)) \rightarrow f(n-5) = f(f(n)) \rightarrow f(n-5-5)=f(f(n-5))=f(f(f(n)))
$$
$$
f(n-5k) = f^{k+1}(n) \quad (H.I)
$$
$$
f(n-5(k+1))=f((n-5)-5k) = f^{k+1}(n-5) = f^{k}f((n-5))=f^{k}f(f(n))=f^{k+2}(n)
$$
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
f(999)=f(f(1004))=f(1001)=998 \\
f(998)=f(f(1003))=f(1000)=997 \\
f(997)=f(f(1002))=f(999) =998
\end{eqnarray}
$$
$$
\therefore f^{2k}(999)=997 \land f^{2k+1}(999) = 998
$$
$$
\therefore f(9)=f(999-5\times 198) = f^{199}(999) = 998
$$